# ListView ContextActions and TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How correctly to combine in ListView ContextActions and Processing of an element choice? I tried this, but the context menu does not work in android.

```
<ListView 
x:Name="WorkoutsListView" 
HasUnevenRows="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding Workouts}">
<!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkout, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteWorkoutCommand, Source={x:Reference ContentPage}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                Text="Delete"
                IsDestructive="True"/>
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateWorkoutCommand, Source={x:Reference ContentPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
            Margin="15,12,10,12"
            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have far better luck attaching a behavior to the ListView rather than the Grid. Feel free to use the following. You may note that it uses `BehaviorBase<T>` rather than `Behavior<T>`. That is because I use the Prism BehaviorBase. If you do opt to use [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), you can also use the [`EventToCommandBehavior`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs) that is built in. Of course you can implement this all yourself. You can find a sample from Xamarin [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior).

```
public class ItemTappedBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Command ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( SelectedItemBehavior ), null );

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return ( ICommand )GetValue( CommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( CommandProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo( ListView bindable )
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo( bindable );
        AssociatedObject.ItemTapped += OnItemTapped;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom( ListView bindable )
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom( bindable );
        AssociatedObject.ItemTapped -= OnItemTapped;
    }

    void OnItemTapped( object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( Command == null || e.Item == null ) return;

        if ( Command.CanExecute( e.Item ) )
            Command.Execute( e.Item );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try.